# Data passed to other pages via hyperlink is being cut off

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that contains 2 `<select>`, the first select auto-populates itself upon page load, while the second select populates itself based on the choice selected in the first select.

To accomplish this, whenever the the select's state changes, the selected value in the first  would be passed to a seperate page where it is used to populate the 2nd `<select>`

***Problem***

The selected value( Food & Beverages in this case) which is passed through the url is being cut off halfway, causing an incomplete string to be send to the processing page for the 2nd , which causes it to be unable to run.

***Steps taken to identify the issue***
I've echoed the values that is passed through the url and only got "Food", with the rest of the string cut off. I've tried replacing the string values to Food and Beverage, and the whole thing works perfectly, leading me to conclude that the string is being cut off due to the ampersand(&) sign which causes the computer to treat the part of the string after the ampersand as another value to be passed through the URL.However, as i did not assign it to a variable, it is not being passed through.

***Question***

Is there any way for me to pass the value without it being cut off?

**Code Extracts:**

**Processing Page**

```
<?PHP
include("cxn.inc");

$query=$cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `BusinessSubCategory` WHERE `BusinessCategory`=:businesscategory");
$query->bindValue(":businesscategory",$_GET['category']);
$query->execute();
$count=$query->rowCount();
if($count>0)
{
    echo"<option id='subcategory' value=''>Please select a SubCategory</option>";
    while($result=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $subcategory=$result['BusinessSubCategory'];
        echo"<option id=$subcategory value=$subcategory >$subcategory</option>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo"<option id='subcategory' value=''>Error,fetch query not run. </option>";
}
?>
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#BusinessCreateCategory').load('getbusinesscategory.php');

$('#BusinessCreateCategory').change(function(){

    var category=$('#BusinessCreateCategory').val();
    window.location.href='getbusinesssubcategory.php?category='+category;

});
```

EDIT:Tried encodeURIComponent, but the data is not being encoded as i can see from the url of the processing apge that it is cut off at the ampersand.HOWEVER, if i were to manually enter the url as a string and then code it using encodeURIComponent, it works wonderfully.CAn anyone shed some light on why i am unable to encode $('#BusinessCreateCategory').val(); ? Thanks!

E.gThis works

```
var category="Food & Beverages";
    var encoded =encodeURIComponent(category);
    window.location.href='getbusinesssubcategory.php?category='+encoded;
```

E.g This does not

```
var category=$('#BusinessCreateCategory').val();
    var encoded= encodeURIComponent(category);
    window.location.href='getbusinesssubcategory.php?category='+encoded;
```

If it helps, the data i am trying to pass through the url is taken from my database.

Comment: Have you tried using php urlencode on the value? http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: I would highly recommend that you don't use a string as your option value, instead use and Auto Incremented Index ie an `id`

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey Why would you recommend using an auto incremented index instead of a string for option values?

Comment: @Ken its cleaner, quicker, you could have two sub categories that are the same name but have different parent categories, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `encodeURIComponent` the value for category before using it in a URL.

```
$('#BusinessCreateCategory').change(function(){

    var category=$('#BusinessCreateCategory').val();
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(category);
    window.location.href='getbusinesssubcategory.php?category='+encoded;

});
```

Ampersand is a special character that garbles the URL you are trying to pass.  Encoding the value should allow you to treat it as a single value.

Comment: I've tried encoding my code as per your example, but the string is still not being encoded?The value that i am trying to pass is drawn straight from my database if that is of any help

Comment: Can you view the exact URL that is being submitted in the browser network panel?  Can you paste it here?

Comment: It looks to me like the php that is rendering your dropdown in the first place is not putting quotes around the value.  The HTML will look like <option value=Food & Beverage> etc.  Without quotes you cannot include spaces in the value.

Answer (score 0):

There is a browser limit to how many characters can pass through. Do you have an example of the complete string that you are trying to pass? I would initially suspect that this could be an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

encodeURIComponent to encode the string being passed.

The value should be encoded but when you query your db it might look for exact match, in case you fail to see any output via the encoded string use decodeURIComponent to decode the string before passing it to db. Check the output at phymyadmin before your formally put the code.